# Trigonometric integral involving the fractional part

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, fractional-part

With $\{\}$ denoting the fractional part function, does the following integral admit a closed-form?
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bigg\{\sec(x)\bigg\}dx$$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you'd expect it to admit a closed form? Or is it just something you wonder about?

Comment: I have expressed in terms of an infinite series yet still wonder if somebody could find its closed-form.

Comment: @KaysTomy, I think it would be nice if you add your series solution as a part of the question or even post your own answer

Comment: Does this answer your question [once you make the substitution $x\to \pi/2 -x$, it's an exact duplicate]? [Trigonometric integral involving the fractional part function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101464/trigonometric-integral-involving-the-fractional-part-function)